# pandas to get the percentage value just the number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am running the below code to get the total count of column  `Type`, the count of string `Simple` from column Complexity and find out how much percentage of value Simple is there in CSV.

I am using below and values are correct. But its returning as below -

```
"Type    11.358464
dtype: float64"
```

I just need the number `11.358464`, please help.

```
import pandas as pd
sdcount = pd.read_csv('cvs1.csv', usecols=['Type']).count()
print(sdcount)
df = pd.read_csv ("csv1.csv")
simpcount = df.Complexity.value_counts().Simple
print(simpcount)
simpcountpercent = (simpcount/sdcount)*100
print(simpcountpercent)
```

Comment: `simpcountpercent.values`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Complexity': ['Simple', 'Simple', 'Simple', 'dd', 'ss', 'aa']})

print (df)
  Complexity
0     Simple
1     Simple
2     Simple
3         dd
4         ss
5         aa

s = df['Complexity'].value_counts(normalize=True)
print (s)
Simple    0.500000
ss        0.166667
dd        0.166667
aa        0.166667
Name: Complexity, dtype: float64
```

And then select by index for scalar:

```
print (s['Simple'])
0.5
```

EDIT:

In your code is problem with:

```
sdcount = pd.read_csv('cvs1.csv', usecols=['Type']).count()
```

output is one element Series instead scalar.

For scalar use:

```
sdcount = pd.read_csv('cvs1.csv', usecols=['Type'])['Type'].count()
```